# Upgraded to 14.04 now HP F2480 aio printer works but scanner does not was OK with 12.04

Tags: 14.04, scanner

After upgrading to 14.04 HP F2480 aio printer works but scanner does not.
It was OK with 12.04.
Please be explicit as I am a newbie.
TIA